# SQL Server : join on uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have two tables `Backup` and `Requests`.

Below is the script for both the tables

**Backup**

```
CREATE TABLE UserBackup(
           FileName varchar(70) NOT NULL,
        )
```

File name is represented by a guid. Sometimes there is some additional information related to the file. Hence we have entries like guid_ADD entried in table.

**Requests**

```
CREATE TABLE Requests(
           RequestId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
           Status int Not null
        )
```

Here are some sample rows :

**UserBackup** table:

```
FileName
15b993cc-e8be-405d-bb9f-0c58b66dcdfe 
4cffe724-3f68-4710-b785-30afde5d52f8 
4cffe724-3f68-4710-b785-30afde5d52f8_Add
7ad22838-ddee-4043-8d1f-6656d2953545
```

**Requests** table:

```
RequestId                              Status
15b993cc-e8be-405d-bb9f-0c58b66dcdfe    1
4cffe724-3f68-4710-b785-30afde5d52f8    1
7ad22838-ddee-4043-8d1f-6656d2953545    2
```

What I need is to return all the rows from userbackup table whose name (the guid) is matches `RequestId` in the `Requests` table and the status is 1. So here is the query I wrote

```
Select * 
from UserBackup
inner join Requests on UserBackup.FileName = Requests.RequestId
where Requests.Status = 1
```

And this works fine. It returns me the following result

```
FileName                                      RequestId                              Status
15b993cc-e8be-405d-bb9f-0c58b66dcdfe          15b993cc-e8be-405d-bb9f-0c58b66dcdfe     1
4cffe724-3f68-4710-b785-30afde5d52f8          4cffe724-3f68-4710-b785-30afde5d52f8     1
4cffe724-3f68-4710-b785-30afde5d52f8_Add      4cffe724-3f68-4710-b785-30afde5d52f8     1
```

This is exactly what I want. But what I don't understand is how it is working. If you notice the result is returning `4cffe724-3f68-4710-b785-30afde5d52f8_Add` row as well. The inner join is on `varchar` and `uniqueidentifier`, and this join instead of working like "Equals to" comparison works like "contains" comparison. I want to know how this works so that I can be sure to use this code without any unexpected scenarios.

Comment: Why is one a GUID and the other VARCHAR??????

Comment: Uh, when you have additional information like `_ADD`, **put that in another column**. This design is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you compare two columns of different data types SQL Server will attempt to do implicit conversion on lower precedence.

The following comes from MSDN docs on  `uniqueidentifier`

> The following example demonstrates the truncation of data when the
>   value is too long for the data type being converted to. Because the
>   uniqueidentifier type is limited to 36 characters, the characters that
>   exceed that length are truncated.

```
DECLARE @ID nvarchar(max) = N'0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0wrong'; 
SELECT @ID, CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, @ID) AS TruncatedValue;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx

Documentation is clear that data is **truncated**

When ever you are unsure about your join operation you can verify `Actual Execution Plan`.

Here is test sample that you can run inside SSMS or SQL Sentry Plan Explorer

```
DECLARE @userbackup TABLE ( _FILENAME VARCHAR(70) )

INSERT INTO @userbackup
    VALUES  ( '15b993cc-e8be-405d-bb9f-0c58b66dcdfe' ),
            ( '4cffe724-3f68-4710-b785-30afde5d52f8' ),
            ( '4cffe724-3f68-4710-b785-30afde5d52f8_Add' )
,           ( '7ad22838-ddee-4043-8d1f-6656d2953545' )


DECLARE @Requests TABLE
    (
     requestID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    ,_Status INT
    )
INSERT INTO @Requests
    VALUES  ( '15b993cc-e8be-405d-bb9f-0c58b66dcdfe', 1 )
,           ( '4cffe724-3f68-4710-b785-30afde5d52f8', 1 )
,           ( '7ad22838-ddee-4043-8d1f-6656d2953545', 2 )

SELECT *
    FROM @userbackup u
    JOIN @Requests r
        ON u.[_FILENAME] = r.requestID
    WHERE r.[_Status] = 1
```

Instead of regular `join` operation SQL Server is doing `HASH MATCH` with `EXPR 1006` in SSMS it is hard to see what is doing but if you open XML file you will find this

```
<ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" />
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(uniqueidentifier,@userbackup.[_FILENAME] as [u].[_FILENAME],0)">
```

When ever in doubt check execution plan and always make sure to match data types when comparing.

This is great blog [Data Mismatch on WHERE Clause might Cause Serious Performance Problems](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/16/data-mismatch-on-where-clause-might-cause-serious-performance-problems.aspx) from Microsoft engineer on exact problem.

Answer (score 8):

The values on both sides of a comparison have to be of the *same* data type. There's no such thing as, say, comparing a `uniqueidentifier` and a `varchar`.

[`uniqueidentifier`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) has a [higher precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) than [`varchar`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) so the `varchar`s will be converted to `uniqueidentifier`s before the comparison occurs.

Unfortunately, you get no error or warning if the string contains more characters than are needed:

```
select CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'4cffe724-3f68-4710-b785-30afde5d52f8_Add')
```

Result:

```
4CFFE724-3F68-4710-B785-30AFDE5D52F8
```

If you want to force the comparison to occur between strings, you'll have to perform an explicit conversion:

```
Select * 
from UserBackup
inner join Requests
on UserBackup.FileName = CONVERT(varchar(70),Requests.RequestId)
where Requests.Status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is the FileName is being converted from varchar to a UniqueIdentifier, and during that process it ignores anything after the first 36 characters.

You can see it in action here

```
Select convert(uniqueidentifier, UserBackup.FileName), FileName
  from UserBackup
```

It works, but to reduce confusion for the next person to come along, you might want to store the RequestId associated with the UserBackup as a GUID in the UserBackup table and join on that.

At the very least put a comment in ;)