# SQL Inner Join: Weird Result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I have data that looks like this:

```
Table_A:

Source     tableName     systemid
A           table_1       123abcA2
B           table_1       222DEFD3
C           table_1       369CCCB3


Table_B:

Source     tableName     systemid
Q          table_2       123abc
R          table_2       222DEF
C          table_2       369CCC
```

I ran the following query:

```
select a.Source, a.tableName, a.systemid as a_systemid, b.systemid as b_systemid
from table_a as a
inner join table_b as b on a.systemid = b.systemid
```

Here is what came back:

```
Source     tableName     a_systemid     b_systemid
A           table_1       123abcA2       123abc
B           table_1       222DEFD3       222def
C           table_1       369CCCB3       369CCC
```

Shouldn't I get nothing returned? As nothing matches.

```
Table A system id = nvarchar data type

Table b systemid = uniqueidentifier data type
```

Comment: the entire query should have returned null... check the data type of each table. I would suggest to add the create table commands to the question

Comment: Your last sentence *"Shouldn't the values in column B be null? Column B only matches part of the values in column A."* would be the expected result of a LEFT OUTER JOIN. An INNER JOIN in this scenario with this exact data sample would return nothing as there are no matches between `A.systemid` and `B.SystemID`.

Comment: I could have swore I typed a left join, silly me :)

Comment: I added the data types of the columns I'm joining on

Comment: [Here is a SQLFiddle with both join types](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/36fc8/2) where the LEFT OUTER JOIN version returns NULL for `table_b.systemid` as expected and the INNER JOIN returns no records, also as expected.

Comment: you have varchar(10) for the systemid values.    That's not what I have.

Comment: Can you post some realistic sample data? You claim that b.systemid is a uniqueidentifier but your data is certainly not that. You need to post the **actual** table design. The answer you seek can be found [here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Posted that SQLFiddle before you shared your data types. `UniqueIdentifier` takes the form `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` but your data does not look like that at all. If there is anything else you are doing in your real join, please share that as well. Something is not as it seems.

Comment: okay, will share tonight when I am home.

Comment: Almost certainly the cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841229/sql-server-join-on-uniqueidentifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit casting is occuring and essentially truncating your string data which causes a match. You need to explicitly cast the uniqueidentifier to an nvarchar(max).

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841229/sql-server-join-on-uniqueidentifier) question and answer.

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE([Source] CHAR(1),tableName VARCHAR(10),systemid nvarchar(max))
DECLARE @t2 TABLE([Source] CHAR(1),tableName VARCHAR(10),systemid uniqueidentifier)
INSERT INTO @t1 SELECT 'A','table_1','15b993cc-e8be-405d-bb9f-0c58b66dcdfe_1'
INSERT INTO @t1 SELECT 'B','table_1','4cffe724-3f68-4710-b785-30afde5d52f8_1'
INSERT INTO @t1 SELECT 'C','table_1','7ad22838-ddee-4043-8d1f-6656d2953545_1'
INSERT INTO @t2 SELECT 'Q','table_2','15b993cc-e8be-405d-bb9f-0c58b66dcdfe'
INSERT INTO @t2 SELECT 'R','table_2','4cffe724-3f68-4710-b785-30afde5d52f8'
INSERT INTO @t2 SELECT 'C','table_2','7ad22838-ddee-4043-8d1f-6656d2953545'

select a.Source, a.tableName, a.systemid as a_systemid, b.systemid as b_systemid
from @t1 as a
inner join @t2 as b on a.systemid = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),b.systemid)
```

As a practice, you should always explicitly cast mismatched datatypes for clarity as well as prevent weird "what is going on?!?!" stuff.